# Changing the color of matplotlib's violin plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, violin-plot

Is there a way to change the color of the `violin` plots in matplotlib?

The default color is this "brownish" color, which is not too bad, but I'd like to color e.g., the first 3 violins differently to highlight them. I don't find any parameter in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.violinplot). Any ideas or hacks to color the violins differently?

[image]

Comment: Can you open a feature request to add that functionality?  Violin plots a a new feature in 1.4 and (apparently) still need some refining.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[`matplotlib.pyplot.violinplot()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.violinplot) says it returns:

> A dictionary mapping each component of the violinplot to a list of the corresponding collection instances created. The dictionary has the following keys:
>
> - `bodies`: A list of the `matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection` instances containing the filled area of each violin.
> - *[...among others...]*

Methods of [`PolyCollection`s](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) include:

- [`set_color(c)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection.set_color) which sets both the facecolor and edgecolor,
- [`set_facecolor(c)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection.set_facecolor) and
- [`set_edgecolor(c)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection.set_edgecolor) all of which take a "matplotlib color arg or sequence of rgba tuples"

So, it looks like you could just loop through the result's body list and modify the facecolor of each:

```
violin_parts = plt.violinplot(...)

for pc in violin_parts['bodies']:
    pc.set_facecolor('red')
    pc.set_edgecolor('black')
```

It is a bit strange though that you can't set this when creating it like the common plot types. I'd guess it's probably because the operation creates so many bits (the aforementioned `PolyCollection` along with 5 other `LineCollections`), that additional arguments would be ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, `for patch, color in zip(vplot['bodies'], colors):
        patch.set_color(color)` did the job!

Comment: Or using `plt.setp` for short, e.g. `plt.setp(violin_parts['bodies'], facecolor='red', edgecolor='black')`

Comment: Just wanted to say that `violin_parts.keys()` will list all different parts you can adjust. For example: `dict_keys(['bodies', 'cmaxes', 'cmins', 'cbars', 'cmedians'])`. 
Then, `dir(violin_parts['cbars'])` will list attributes you can set. For example: `violin_parts['cbars'].set_linewidth(1)`

Answer (score 18):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

rrred = '#ff2222'
bluuu = '#2222ff'
x = np.arange(2, 25)
y = np.array([xi * np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10**3) for xi in x]).T

# Create violin plot objects:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (8,8))
violin_parts = ax.violinplot(y, x, widths = 0.9, showmeans = True, showextrema = True, showmedians = True)

# Make all the violin statistics marks red:
for partname in ('cbars','cmins','cmaxes','cmeans','cmedians'):
    vp = violin_parts[partname]
    vp.set_edgecolor(rrred)
    vp.set_linewidth(1)

# Make the violin body blue with a red border:
for vp in violin_parts['bodies']:
    vp.set_facecolor(bluuu)
    vp.set_edgecolor(rrred)
    vp.set_linewidth(1)
    vp.set_alpha(0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Since you don't know whether means etc. are enabled, you could simply loop through all available parts with `for partname in violin_parts`. However, as the `'bodies'` part is a list itself, you'd have to skip that one (with `if partname == 'bodies': continue`) and handle it manually. (Based on what I learned from the comments on @Nick T's answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have 3 vectors: data1, data2, data3; and you have plotted your matplotlib violinplots in one figure; then, to set the color of the **median line** and **body facecolor** specific for each sub-violinplot you can use:

```
colors = ['Blue', 'Green', 'Purple']

# Set the color of the violin patches
for pc, color in zip(plots['bodies'], colors):
    pc.set_facecolor(color)

# Set the color of the median lines
plots['cmedians'].set_colors(colors)
```

The full example:

```
# Set up the figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# Create a list of the data to be plotted
data = [data1, data2, data3]

# Set the colors for the violins based on the category
colors = ['Blue', 'Green', 'Purple']

# Create the violin plot
plots = ax.violinplot(data, vert=False, showmedians=True, showextrema=False, widths=1)

# Set the color of the violin patches
for pc, color in zip(plots['bodies'], colors):
    pc.set_facecolor(color)

# Set the color of the median lines
plots['cmedians'].set_colors(colors)

# Set the labels
ax1.set_yticks([1, 2, 3], labels=['category1', 'category2', 'category3'])

ax1.invert_yaxis() # ranking from top to bottom: invert yaxis

plt.show()
```

[image: Example for matplotlib violin plots with different colors]

Comment: Thanks! This is actually the only complete answer (showing how to change colors of all elements, not only the violin body.) Adding a figure could greatly improve its visibility.