# Matplotlib's violinplot doesn't follow rcParam

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is matplotlib version 1.5.0. I cannot seem to set the `rcParams` in a way that `violinpot` will obey the facecolors. I've set both the `prop_cyle` and the `facecolor` keys for `axes` and `patch` respectively to no avail. For example the code below ....

```
import matplotlib
from cycler import cycler


matplotlib.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler('color', ['pink','purple','salmon'])
matplotlib.rcParams['patch.facecolor'] = 'pink'
matplotlib.rcParams['patch.edgecolor'] = 'blue'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import randn

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

X = randn(100)

ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
for i in range(3):
    ax.hist(X+2*i)

ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
for i in range(3):
    ax.violinplot(X+2*i)

plt.show()
```

.... produces:

[image: no image description here]

It's hard to discern from the picture, but the edge color does in fact get set to blue in the violinplot. There seems to be a default alpha setting with `violinplot` which makes this not quite apparent. However, the facecolors obviously remain at the default. Why is this, and can I force it to use the `rcParams` values? I realize that [I can set the facecolors manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291479/changing-the-color-of-matplotlibs-violin-plots) after plotting, but I'd rather just have the plots obey the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the red and yellow colors are hard-coded in the code for violonplot unfortunately.

```
bodies += [fill(stats['coords'],
                            -vals + pos,
                            vals + pos,
                            facecolor='y',
                            alpha=0.3)]
(...)
artists['cmeans'] = perp_lines(means, pmins, pmaxes, colors='r')
```

I suggest you drop a feature request on the [matplotlib github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues)

Comment: I see. I will do that. Thanks